# What is the lowest CR creature that has Legendary Actions?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters

What is the lowest CR creature that has Legendary Actions?

I'm open to answers referencing creatures from any officially published WotC resources, including named NPCs in published adventures or DDAL (Adventurers League).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

### We have a winner at CR 3

As of now, according to [a search on DnD Beyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters?filter-type=0&filter-search=&filter-cr-min=1&filter-cr-max=8&filter-armor-class-min=&filter-armor-class-max=&filter-average-hp-min=&filter-average-hp-max=&filter-is-legendary=t&filter-has-lair=), there are two creatures who win at CR 3:

There is the [Fleecemane Lion](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/fleecemane-lion) from the *Mythic Odysseys of Theros*. There is also Bol'bara who is from the *Explorer's Guide to Wildmount*. There are some specific requirements for them to have legendary actions which are mentioned in [mdrichey's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/166483). Thanks to mdrichey for finding this option in the first place.

---

Below is my previous answer prior to the release of *Wildmount*:

There are two creatures tied at CR 4 that have legendary actions:

The [Yestabrod](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/yestabrod) from Out of the Abyss and the [Thessalhydra](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/thessalhydra) from [Hunt for the Thessalhydra](https://www.dndbeyond.com/marketplace/source/hunt-for-the-thessalhydra).

There is also the honorable mentions of the [Merrenoloth](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/merrenoloth) from Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes; a CR 3 character with lair and regional actions though no legendary actions.

There is also, as mdrichey points out, the [Unicorn](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/unicorn) at CR 5 from the *Monster Manual*, who has legendary actions, is not from a specific module, and is not a specific (single) character/creature. Thanks, again, to mdrichey for bringing up the Unicorn as an option/example.

Answer (score 13):

### Bol'bara (CR 3)

The adventure "Unwelcome Spirits," contained in *Explorer's Guide to Wildmount*, contains a CR 3

> goblin warlock

named [Bol'bara](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/bolbara), who has legendary actions when she

> is fully possessed by her patron, the shadow demon known as Trush.

### Honorable Mention: Unicorn

[Medix2's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/166419/48191) mentions a couple of CR 4 monsters from other published adventures that have legendary actions. I think it is also worth mentioning that the lowest CR monster with legendary actions that is not tied to a specific published adventure is the CR 5 [unicorn](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/unicorn).

Comment: I Incorporated some of your answer into my own. If you don't think I gave out credit correctly or that it should be restructured, feel free to explain

Comment: Well would you look at that, mere hours after I accepted an answer, the new book came out with a different answer. Although I won't change the accepted answer, I feel that at least you deserved a +1.